# python: determine if list A contains a value different from list B

Tags: python, iteration

I'm trying to determine if a list `A` contains a value different from two other values, which make up list `B` (`0` and `1`):

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]  # False
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # False
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]  # False
[0, 1, 0, 2, 0]  # True
```

Here's what I have so far but I feel like there's a nice one-liner or a generally much more efficient way:

```
indicator = False
A = [0, 1, 0, 2, 0]
B = [0, 1]
for i in A:
    if i not in B:
        indicator = True
```

Comment: Indentation fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set.issubset()` for this purpose.

```
if not set(A).issubset(B):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Input:

```
A = [0, 1, 0, 2, 0]
B = [0, 1]
```

Output: `True`

Input:

```
A = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
B = [0, 1]
```

Output: `False`

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of a solution is at best linear, meaning that in the worst case you will have to check all the items in the list. That's, however, the **worst** case. So, if performance is the issue, you can just stop when you find the first different value:

```
for i in A:
    if i not in B:
       indicator = True
       break
```

If in a very long list of 20 billion values the first item is already not in B, the outer loop will execute only one time and exit, instead of 20 billion!
It will not guarantee you to run faster -the algorithm is still linear, if you can stop earlier depends on the values in the list- but with a bit of luck you may end up saving a significant amount of time.

Also note that the `i not in B`, as it is, is linear in complexity. Every time you execute that line, it will implicitly iterate on the B list values. If A contains N elements and B contains M elements, the total number of operations will be N*M in the worst case scenario. For very small M is ok, but for large lists of values you could consider a `set`. If B is a set, the check `i not in B` would be executed in constant time, so that the total number of operations will scale only with N.

If your problem is having a one-liner, as previous answer pointed out, a `set` is a collection of unique items, so using them you can obtain elegant one-liners with linear complexity. My version:

```
indicator = not(set(array) == set(allowed_values))
```

Generating the set, however, requires to read all the input array, which again could be slower than the first solution when you have very large arrays and you're in a lucky situation: for example when the first number of the array is not in your accepted values.

Comment: This has O(N*\*2) performance.  An O(n) solution is preferable.

Comment: what? it is definitely linear, or maximum N*M, but see the comment on the `i not in B`. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's O(n*\*2).  If A has 100 elements and B has 100 elements, then the inner loop executes 10,000 times.  That's O(n*\*2).

Comment: But you can do it in linear time if you use a set for the second check, like I explained in the answer. In any case, O(N^2) is somewhat different than O(N*M), with N and M the length of two arrays. I tried to expand to make it clearer

Comment: Yes, that is true.  But there's a much more direct way to do this.

Comment: Also, why use `True if x == y else False`?  That's just `x == y`.

Comment: That's true, thanks. Will edit. But still, what is the more direct way to do this?

Comment: Look at my posted answer.  It's a simple, efficient expression.  It was the first correct solution posted.

Comment: And it will read all the array also when the first number is 5. It may be suboptimal in many cases.

Comment: I guess the point of my longer answer was not very clear. I'll edit to explain it better. Thanks.